# Ionic 4 Refresher is not passing in the refresher object so I can’t complete it

Tags: angular, ionic4, swiperefreshlayout, pull-to-refresh

When trying to complete the refresher, I’m getting the error

> TypeError: refresher.complete is not a function.

**.html:**

```
<ion-refresher #refresherRef slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="load($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content
    pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
    pullingText="Pull to refresh"
    refreshingSpinner="circles"
    refreshingText="Refreshing...">
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
```

**.ts**

```
load(refresher) {
    let postData = new FormData();
    postData.append('user_id', this.userData.userId);

    this.authService.postData(postData, "is_verified_or_not.php").then((result) => {
      this.responseData = result;

      this.success = this.responseData.success;
      if (this.success == 1) {
        refresher.complete();
        let userDeatil = this.responseData.users_details;
        for (let data1 of userDeatil) {
        }
      } else {
        this.message = this.responseData.message;
        refresher.complete();
        this.showToast(this.message);
      }
    }, (err) => {
      refresher.complete();
      console.log("Error", err);
    });
  }
```

I followed the instructions from https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-refresher-is-not-passing-in-the-refresher-object-so-i-cant-complete-it/144213

I tried:

```
@ViewChild("refresherRef") refresherRef: Refresher;

load(refresher: Refresher) {
    this.refresherRef.complete();
}
```

But it gives me an error at `@ViewChild("refresherRef")`

> Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554) core.d.ts(8436, 47): An
>   argument for 'opts' was not provided.

And at **Refresher** in same line `@ViewChild("refresherRef") refresherRef: Refresher;`

> Cannot find name 'Refresher'.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 8 , ViewChild takes 2 parameters

Try replacing

@ViewChild("refresherRef")

with

@ViewChild("refresherRef", { static: false } )

Comment: Thanks.! It solved but the second error remains the same. `Cannot find name 'Refresher'`

Comment: try the following line : @ViewChild('refresherRef', { static: false }) Refresher: ElementRef;

Comment: import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

Comment: I import it but now it gives me error on both line `load(refresher: Refresher) {
    this.refresherRef.complete();
  }`   `Cannot find name 'Refresher'.` and  `Property 'refresherRef' does not exist on type 'Tab1Page'.`

Comment: You also have to import 'Refresher' to use it in your current component.

Comment: Thank You. It solved I just have to change in my code from `refresher.complete();` to `refresher.target.complete();` in my code. There is no need to add **@ViewChild("refresherRef", { static: false } )**